# How to maintain UI responsive with long-running slot

Tags: python, qt, qml, qthread, pyside2

I have a python-defined worker `QObject` that has a slow `work()` slot that is called by the QML UI (in my actual UI, the method is called on each item in a `FolderListModel` dynamically as the user goes through the list, but for he sample code I'm just calling it on the window's completion as an example).

I'd like to run the slow `work` asynchronously to prevent the UI from blocking. I thought to do so by moving the Worker instance on a QThread and calling the slot there, but this is not working, as the UI is still blocked waiting for the result of `work()` to come.

This is the code of my attempt so far:

mcve.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Window 2.13

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Main Window")

    Component.onCompleted: console.log(worker.work("I'm done!")) // not the actual usage, see note in the question
}
```

mcve.py:

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl, QThread, QObject, Slot
from time import sleep

class Worker(QObject):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)

  @Slot(str, result=str)
  def work(self, path):
    sleep(5) # do something lengthy
    return path

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    workerThread = QThread()
    worker = Worker()
    worker.moveToThread(workerThread)
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("worker", worker)
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile('mcve.qml'))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How do I invoke `work()` asynchronously so that only when it's done its effects are applied? And, as a bonus, what am I doing/understanding wrong in the use of QThreads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Explanation:

- **Where is the "work" method currently executed?** Well, if you add the following code and check what you get:

```py
# ...

import threading

class Worker(QObject):
    @Slot(str, result=str)
    def work(self, path):
        print(threading.current_thread())
        sleep(5)  # do something lengthy
        return path

# ...
```

Output:

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140409078408832)>
qml: I'm done!
```

As you can see the "work" method is executed in the main thread causing it to block the GUI.

- **Why is the "work" method executed in main thread?** A method or function is executed in the context where it is called, in your case in QML that is executed in the main thread.
- **So how do you execute a method in the thread where the QObject lives?** Well you have to do it asynchronously using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` (this method is not possible in PySide2 for a bug), through the call of a signal, or using `QTimer::singleShot()`.

---

### Solution:

In these cases it is better to create a bridge(QObject) that calls the function/method that is executed in another thread, and to notify the changes through the signals.

```py
import sys
from time import sleep
from functools import partial

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtQml


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    resultChaged = QtCore.Signal(str)

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def work(self, path):
        sleep(5)  # do something lengthy
        self.resultChaged.emit(path)


class Bridge(QtCore.QObject):
    startSignal = QtCore.Signal(str)
    resultChaged = QtCore.Signal(str, arguments=["result"])

    def __init__(self, obj, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.m_obj = obj
        self.m_obj.resultChaged.connect(self.resultChaged)
        self.startSignal.connect(self.m_obj.work)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()

    workerThread = QtCore.QThread()
    workerThread.start()

    worker = Worker()
    worker.moveToThread(workerThread)

    bridge = Bridge(worker)

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("bridge", bridge)
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile("mcve.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    ret = app.exec_()
    workerThread.quit()
    workerThread.wait()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Window 2.13

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Main Window")

    Component.onCompleted: bridge.startSignal("I'm done!")

    Connections{
        target: bridge
        onResultChaged: console.log(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a perfect answer.

Comment: It is indeed. Thank you very much for such a high-quality and well explained answer! I do have a couple of new doubts raised by your solution which I might ask about, but I'll first implement this and try to understand it completely :)